# the virtual memory addresses returned by shmat() points different hardware memory locations

Tags: c, linux, memory, arm, shared-memory

I have two processes, each can take the **same `shmid`** from `shmget()`.

In these two processes, `shmat()` gives different memory addresses.

The addresses are always the same for each of the process:

```
Process1: 0x41b31000
Process2: 0x4017d000
```

I do not think the addresses are virtual addreses as stated the answer which is written in the question below, beside, if these addresses are virtual addresses, these have to point the same hardware address. **However, the content of these addresses is not same.**

I'm cross compiling for ARM Processor, my program is running without error or problem in x86 Debian Lenny.

I'm aware of that the question, but the problem is not much that ease - [shmat() is returning a different "shmaddr" for same "shmkey"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434974/shmat-is-returning-a-different-shmaddr-for-same-shmkey) -

Comment: Yes, the addresses are different. What is the problem?

Comment: The content of the addresses must be the same, but everytime I access the 0x4017d000, I read different content.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit the question so that it contains the problem. As it stands now, there's no useful content in it.

Comment: I've just edited it..

Comment: The title is still misleading, the man page explicitly says that it is OK for the addresses to be different in different processes. Anyway, the contents of the memory ought to be the same. Can you reproduce the problem in a small self-contained example?

Comment: If you need the address to be the same in both processes, do you provide the same address as the `shmaddr` (second) argument to the [`shmat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shmat.html) function?  Is there a reason you can't?  You're probably passing 0 at the moment.

Comment: These **are** virtual addresses.

Comment: And this is not a cache, smp or weak memory issue?

Comment: I found a mailing list which says it's about L2 Cache, but I apply the patch they said, there is no change. I'm sure now, it's about the kernel that I'm compiling for my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was about memory alignment.

I have a huge data with starting 1 byte whether it is clean or not, but that 1 byte cost for 2 week.

There is no problem with Shared memory on ARM or with operating system.

One reason, my fault.

Answer (score 4):

The addresses returned by `shmat` are virtual addresses.

The same physical memory may be mapped to different virtual addresses in different processes. (It is even possible for the same physical memory to be mapped to different virtual addresses within one process; the operating system can set the virtual-to-physical translation so that multiple virtual addresses map to the same physical memory.)

If `shmat` returns address `a` in process `A` and mapping the same shared memory segment returns address `b` in process `B`, then the data at `a` in process `A` should be the same as the data in `b` in process `B`. If it is not, then something is wrong, which may include: You did not actually map the same shared memory segment, you did not compare the data correctly, or (very unlikely) there is a bug in the shared-memory software or the operating system.

Comment: I'm aware of that already, problem is the allocated content, with shmget, is not well aligned I guess.

Comment: @EnesUnal No. It's about your code. shmat() works perfectly well.

Comment: Not in my arm machine, though. It's perfect in x86 Linux.